# How to identify type of SIM?

Tags: android, sim-card

I am developing an application where I need to check type SIM based on that I need to perform calls . I am able to get network type but I am not able to get type of SIM he is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

determine the type of sim card sim / uim / usim:

```
 / / Get SIMType 

　　

The string simType = "unknown";

/ / Get the system, to obtain the sim data 　　

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

/ / Get the cell phone SIMType 　　

int type = tm.getNetworkType (); 　　

/ / Determine the type of value, and named 　

if (type == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS) { 　　

simType = "USIM";

/ / Type defined for UMTS USIM card for wcdma 　　

} Else if (type == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GPRS) { 　　

simType = "SIM";

/ / Type defined for GPRS GPRS SIM card 　　

} Else if (

type == TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_EDGE) { 　　

simType = "SIM";

/ / Type defined for EDGE-EDGE SIM card 　　

} Else { 　　

simType = "UIM";

/ / Type is unknown definition of UIM card for cdma 　　

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dude use this

```
        TelephonyManager telephone = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String sim_nul = telephone.getSimSerialNumber();
        String op_name = telephone.getNetworkOperatorName();
```

here u will get **Sim number** as well as **Operator** name like Vodafone etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
 final TelephonyManagertm(TelephonyManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService
(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

  String deviceid = tm.getDeviceId();

  String sim_operatorname=tm.getSimOperatorName();

  String sim_number=tm.getSimSerialNumber();

 String manufacturer_name =Build.MANUFACTURER.toString().trim();
```